# How to create graph in c#.net

Tags: c#, bar-chart

```
ChartArea ChartArea1 = new ChartArea();
Legend Legend1 = new Legend();
Series Series1 = new Series();
dynamic Chart1 = new Chart();
this.Controls.Add(Chart1);

ChartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1";
Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(ChartArea1);
Legend1.Name = "Legend1";
Chart1.Legends.Add(Legend1);
Chart1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(210, 241);
Chart1.Name = "Chart1";
Series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
Series1.Legend = "Legend1";
Series1.Name = "Series1";
Chart1.Series.Add(Series1);
Chart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(837, 346);
Chart1.TabIndex = 0;
Chart1.Text = "Chart1";

Chart1.Series("Series1").XValueMember = "subjects";
Chart1.Series("Series1").YValueMembers = "srno";

Chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables("create_exam_next");
Chart1.BringToFront();
```

I use above code but it gives error for **'dynamic'** keyword .I use MSchart .It gives error because i use visual studio 2008 and .net framework 3.5.

Comment: [This question is arguably rudimentary](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=dynamic+keyword+.net&rlz=1C1CHMD_enAU565AU565&oq=dynamic+keyword+.net&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.407j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# keyword `dynamic` is only available above .Net 4.0 ([see basic instroduction](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/69407/The-Dynamic-Keyword-in-C)).

I strongly recommend you to upgrade your project to .Net 4.5 and Visual Studio 2013 (there's a free version) unless your company or school prohibit it.

To quick fix, change the line of `dynamic` to `Chart` as below.

```
Chart Chart1 = new Chart();
```